# Gradle Java debugging project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I've used previously `maven 3` and it was easy to run anything from `IntelliJ IDEA 13`, be at main classes or tests - it worked through maven settings. But now I am trying to debug my java project in IDEA with `Gradle 1.11`. The problem is that idea now creates /out/* directory and trying to run my classes from there instead of using gradle settings and build setups - I mean, with maven I could debug my java project by this:

1. Set debug configurations
2. Run it under debug
3. 2 step will call `maven install` and will run my java project from `target/classes/` directory

But with gradle project idea not uses gradle structure.

How can I debug my java project right from IDEA IDE with gradle?

P.S. I can run `gradle test` under debug in IDEA and it works perfectly, but I need something like `gradle debug` or `gradle run` to set breakpoint in IDE, run my Main class and launch my java application through IDE. Hope it is clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was solved by using `application plugin` of gradle.

In `build.gradle` we need to apply this plugin by adding line:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

And setup main class name:

```
mainClassName = "Main"
```

(Main is my main class).

After that in IDEA we need to create configuration to run gradle's `run`-task and run it under debug.

But if you have a `distribution` plugin applied to in your project they will conflict. You need to delete the line of applying `distribution` plugin and any section of this plugin like `distributions {...`

[Application plugin information](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Comment: Also, if you want to supply command line arguments to the app, add a line `run.args "arg1", "arg2", ...` (this line configures `args` for the `run` task which is defined by the application plugin)